# Como fazer soma de um field de classes diferentes e de apps diferentes?

Tags: python, django, sum

Ola, tenho uma classe num app django chamado produto:

```
class produto(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    quantidade = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    valor = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.descricao)
```

e tenho outra classe num app chamado estoque que sera responsavel pela compra de produtos e consequentemente ira atualizar o produto.quantidade acima!! a classe estoque abaixo

```
class estoque(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(produto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unidade = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

como somar a quantidade de produto pela unidade do estoque uma vez que o saldo anterior sera somado a nova compra?? perdao se nao fui muito claro na pergunta

Comment: Como somar onde? Numa view? Nas propriedades de algum dos modelos? Tens de editar a pergunta e mostrar o que estás a tentar fazer e qual o erro que encontraste.

Comment: é um controle de estoque, quero adicionar mais produtos e a medida que eu adiciono o field quantidade do produto é alterado (somado a quantidade que eu comprei) entende?

Comment: Ainda não fico claro. Onde os dois apps estão? Como os dois app se comunicam?

Comment: entendo!! um amigo disse que meu problema eu resolvo com o django Signals, sao dois apps do mesmo projeto!! o fild unidade do app estoque atualizara o field quantidade do app produto!!